# MUC and PubSub hosts for clustered ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I'm running an ejabberd (20.04) node `ejabberd@chat.example.com` for the virtual host `chat.example.com`.  It has MUC and PubSub enabled with hosts `muc.chat.example.com` and `pubsub.chat.example.com`, respectively.  All that works fine.

Now I want to cluster the node, and add `ejabberd@other.example.com` as another node also serving the virtual host `chat.example.com`.  That seems to work fine as well.

But I'm wondering what I need to do with MUC and PubSub.  Should the second node also be configured with `muc.chat.example.com` and `pubsub.chat.example.com` and it will just work fine?  Or do I need to configure custom `hosts` for the second node's `mod_muc` and `mod_pubsub` modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you can enable those modules in the new node too, with the same configuration than the first node, and ensure the table used by those modules is synchronized between both nodes. That would allow clients to create rooms in either node, and users of either node could join that room.

Comment: Ok cool.  I tried it (using the same `host` configured for the modules on both nodes) and it seems to work fine indeed.  Thanks!